# How do I add Advertising in my Android Apps?

Tags: android, ads

Did google provide some special things or how do you add Adv. in your apps?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is no built-in API for using advertising; that was probably considered to be excessively monopolistic or anti competitive.  There are, however, multiple providers for advertising for Android platforms;  the one that is owned by Google is [AdMob](http://www.admob.com/appdevs).  There ought to be some documentation on their site as to how it works.

Answer (score 4):

[AdMob](http://www.admob.com/appdevs) is one of the more popular in-app advertising SDK's and has been acquired by Google. I'd sign up for an account and take a look at their developer wiki and docs.

Answer (score 1):

AdMob is One of the best api to put add to your application

Here is link:
https://apps.admob.com/admob/signup